# I need help getting error using Buildozer

Tags: python, android, windows-subsystem-for-linux, kivy-language, buildozer

Here is the error that I keep getting using the Windows Subsystem for linux
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eodV9.png)]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFnJM.png)

Okay so what I have tried so far,

1. Change the requirements in the buildozer.spec kivy  2.0.0 to 1.9.0, this was just a test.
2. I changed kivymd 0.104.2 sdl2_ttf 2.0.15I
3. I also noticed while watching a YouTube video that android.logcat_filters equal *:S python:D was commented out so I uncommented that.
4. The change I tried next was in android.sdk from 20 to 19c. Next I was really desperate to fix this, and so I found a tutorial for buildozer and found [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzsvN3fuBA0&t=204s).

I have tried all the commands that he recommended and that are in the description. I realized half way through that I had forgot to put my code in the main.py file so I fixed that. I also tried to change my WSL to version 2 but it was already version 2.  I was expecting this to run the buildozer command find, and I have gotten this error multiple times with none of the mentioned things fixing it.
[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6gNpSuE01qE) was the initial guide I was watching to make this work.

Comment: Do not post images of text. Post them just as text (with optional formatting)

Comment: Cant because it recognizes as code

Comment: What?  How does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The error in your log says not to have spaces in the dir path.

The file path shown includes your Windows username which is `"Gregory Bernbrock"` which you might need to change into `"Gregory_Bernbrock"` to pass that error. Or move the project into the Linux filesystem where the path has no spaces.